# Drupal Theming and Caching Issues

Tags: views, theming, caching

There is a content type in a view who's display is based on a theming template. In this example, the template is called views-view-fields--article-list.tpl.php . This Case Study/Articles list template works great and as expected on the local testing server. Seriously, everything is working fantastico! Changes made to this template act as expected locally.

However, when the file is uploaded to the production server, changes to the template do not seem to be responding at all. Even after the cache is cleared, the changes are not taking effect. In fact, I deleted the template all together to see if that would cause any disruption, and nothing. It still behaves the same way. Also, flushed the cache in the top left of the admin menu.

So, question is...
Is there some sort of database change that needs to happen when I update the template locally and then upload to the server? Or, is there just something missing in general that is not allowing Drupal to re-scan the template files on the production server?

The server resides on bluehost, if that would be relevant, but I believe the issue is something in my Drupal files.

Ayuda, por favor?

---- I thought the below was the problem, but in looking closer, there is a weird caching problem with this file!!! It is still doing this and changes made to it are not refreshing normally. It must have something to do witgh the view's settings.

---

Here was the source of my confusion. When clearing the cache, the server wasn't responding to the changes I made in the template file. I'm still not sure what the original problem was. :( However, I had removed the template file and placed all the code from that file into the last view's 'Rewrite the output of this field option, and had re-formatted it to the correct format. But, I was seeing everything double (and broken), and assumed it was the old template file adding in its own code, thus the odd double vision!

What I forgot was to go to each field in the view UI and exclude its Display. So, yes  Jimajamma, it was at the end a palm to forehead slapping! Thanks for the troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: sounds like a naming issue.  have you gone into Views itself (Style Settings/Theme Information) and checked what template files it is looking for to make sure it is looking for this exactly named template?  It could be something there or perhaps more palm to forehead slapping like uploading the template into the wrong theme directory.

Comment: Yes, the template's theme suggestion is available both locally and on the production server. I have removed the file from the production server, but the server still thinks it is there. However on my local machine w the exact directory structure and file setup, the system knows that it is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the file has the right permissions when uploaded to the server? at least make sure the webserver user has read access to it.

Comment: I've removed the file from the server completely and still the server thinks it is there in it's old form. Also re-uploaded it and changed the permissions to 755, and still it reads the old original file. What do you think the permissions should be? They were origionally 644 ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the case, but if you have [APC's stat set to 0](http://php.net/apc.configuration#ini.apc.stat) you need to flush the APC cache or restart php when changing PHP file's contents.

```
<?php
// Flush the op-code cache in APC.
apc_clear_cache('opcode');
?>
```